# Cross compile PHP for arm - error cannot run test

Tags: php, cross-compiling, armv7, cortex-a

I'm trying to compile PHP 5.6.36 (downloaded on PHP website) for cortex A6 - armv7 platform.

I configured the compiler like this :

```
./configure --host=arm CC="arm-gad-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/gad/1.0.0/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-gad-linux-gnueabi" --disable-dom  --without-iconv --without-openssl --without-pear --without-sqlite3 --disable-pdo --without-pdo-sqlite --disable-phar
```

But I get this error :

```
checking for strcasestr... configure: error: in `/home/PHP/php-5.6.36':
```

`configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling`

Ask me if you need more precision.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

When you are cross-compiling you are creating binaries which will not run (test) on the system where you are compiling. Obvs.

However whoever wrote the configure script didn't think people would be cross-compiling. This should be flagged as a bug to the maintainer.

Comment: Yes I understood that testing isn't possible on my OS. I would like to disable these tests, but I don't know if it's possible. PHP is very used so I think they thought about cross-compiling.

Comment: Of course it's possible - rewrite the m4 file so it doesn't run the tests.

Comment: Thanks, finally I edit the configure file to remove "exit 1"  when tests aren't possible.